apt-get upgrade and apt-get full-upgrade
Hi I administer several kubernetes clusters, 4 total that run on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and am trying to get a patching procedure together.
I want to patch each cluster of Ubuntu servers one at a time, two weeks apart.
I want to use this mini-string of commands to do so:
sudo -s -- <<EOF
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get full-upgrade -y
apt-get autoremove -y
apt-get autoclean -y
EOF
What I really want to do is change the apt-get upgrade command to apt-get upgrade --download-only and do this on all the nodes in each cluster all at once.
Then when I'm ready to install these packages on each cluster it only installs what was downloaded. I understand to do that I have to use apt-get upgrade --no-download --ignore missing.
So my real question is how would that work if I want to use the apt-get full-upgrade command also? So these clusters are going to be patched 2 weeks apart how do I insure that they get
the exact same full-upgrades? Does it do the full-upgrade based on what was downloaded by the apt-get upgrade --download-only command?
I also want to point that I need to stay at version 20.04 because the kubernetes platform that I'm using only supports 20.04

I also want to point that I need to stay at version 18.04 because the kubernetes platform that I'm using only supports 18.04 We don't support it anymore as it has reached end of life. Please contact the authors of the kubernetes platform so that they support latest Ubuntu LTS

they don't support anything past 18.04. I can't make them change this. can you answer my question about the upgrade and full-upgrade commands? that's what I really need addressed.

So, you want to achieve the same thing with full-upgrade what you were trying to do with just upgrade?

correction its version 20.04 not 18.04, sorry. and yes I want to do the same thing with full-upgrade. I tried it another version on my home computer and it didn't give me any errors, but not sure if it worked.

Can you tell us why you want to use full-upgrade instead of upgrade? From what I understand, you just want to download the upgrades for identical systems and perform them offline in one go, right?
